# radio + label hot to get correct values (array)

Tags: jquery, arrays, radio-button, label

I'm trying to get correct values form labels (radio). When I click label, I'm getting value but when I click another one (label), I'm getting value from the first label and I need to click it once again to get two values to my array.

I'm gonna hide radio buttons as I want to use only labels. How I can avoid this behavior ?

Have a look:

```
var radioChecked = $('#radioinstant :radio').is(':checked');

$('#radioinstant :radio').click(function() {
        radioChecked = !radioChecked;
    $(this).attr('checked', radioChecked);
});

var additionalProducts = new Array;

    $(".chk").click(function() {
        additionalProducts=[];
        $('.chk:checked').each(function() {
            additionalProducts.push($(this).val());
        });
        console.log(additionalProducts);
        alert(additionalProducts);
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qfagc/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're clearing the array on every click.

```
var additionalProducts = new Array;   <--- this creates the array

    $(".chk").click(function() {
        additionalProducts=[];     <--- this clears the array on EVERY CLICK
        $('.chk:checked').each(function() {
            additionalProducts.push($(this).val());
        });
        console.log(additionalProducts);
        alert(additionalProducts);
    });
```